# Is there some way to get elasticsearch index data from RAM?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, elk

I have 60gb text file and I want to search by text field in it. My plan is to put the file into Elasticsearch and setup search there.

But it might be that searching in text file would by quicker if reading file from RAM.

So the question is: Is there some way to read Elasticsearch index from RAM and search in RAM. It helps me to compare speed of searching into Elasticsearch and searching into text file(json,.pickle of other format).

I tried to read from the .pickle file using python.
The version of Elasticsearch is 7.1.

Comment: "read Elasticsearch index from RAM and search in RAM" is exactly what ES does :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it is not. In the first versions of ES (see https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/index-modules-store.html) it was possible, but not anymore. You should rely on ES to cache the contents that are more frequently used, but there is nothing you can do to tell it to store contents in memory.

Comment: Thank you for the useful answer.